# Webscraping more than one result at a time

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, gm-xmlhttprequest

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have an array with the words "one, two, three" in it, and I want to use it to search up 3 results on google, and return the results all at once. So, search up the word "one", search up the word "two", search up the word "three", return the results of all three searches.

**What I currently know how to do:**

Right now, I only know how to search up the results once, and that's it. I don't know how to do more than 1 search. How would I go about doing more than 1 search at once? Any example codes would be greatly appreciated.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        google
// @match       *^https://www.google.com/search?q=one*
// @version     1
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at document-end

// ==/UserScript==

var html;
var text;
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];

html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
text = html.innerHTML;
console.log(text);
```